# Minify CSS and JS in prestashop

Tags: css, performance, prestashop, pagespeed

I have an speed optimization module in prestashop that minifies css and js.

When I minify css my webpage is all messed up, so I guees some css causes error when minified, Is there a way to know which minified code is causing the problem?

Is there a way to choose which css files to minify? or do i have to do it manually?

Any advice to do it?

Comment: What specific issues are you seeing? What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, PrestaShop has CCC by default, isn't it enough for you? You will find option related to minifcation in Advanced Preferences -> Performance for PrestaShop 1.6 and Configure -> Advanced -> Performance in 1.7

Answer (score 0):

sorry , this ccc will slow your site.
monify directly